# Does any one know how to fetch last entered value from a column which has formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet (Sheet 1) which have data from day 1 to end of the month in two columns (column A & B). In sheet 2 i am maintaining the sum of each day, ie column A+B from sheet 1. So in sheet 2 i have formula in each row to add column A+B from sheet 1. I need to fetch the last displayed (or last entry) non-zero value from this column in sheet 2 which contains the formula and display it in another cell in sheet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For last non-zero value try this formula assuming data in `A2:A100`, change as required

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A100<>0),A2:A100)`